# java create a TIF file

Tags: java, tiff, jai

I've got an awt image (bw) coming from a scanner, I'd like to save it in a TIF file, I tried with JAI but it has a poor documentation so I'm not able to understand some JAI.create parameters.

Thx in advance.

Comment: post what you have tried and failed. which parameters you do not understand?

Comment: Does this help with JAI at all?
http://goo.gl/zexwE

Comment: I don't understand JAI.create(opName,somethingelse) what does stand for opName? opName is a String how can I find all opName possible?

Comment: Thanks for Your suggestion paranoid-android, the file that creates is empty (0 Kb) it seems like tiff plugin is not installed.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to use JAI for image read/write operations.
javax.imageio.ImageIO doing good job with it. I.e. to write TIFF use something like:

```
ImageIO.write(img, "TIFF", new File(fileName));
```

But if you have to use JAI, it will be something like:

```
//load image
PlanarImage myImageOp = JAI.create("FileLoad", srcImgFile);

//here do some stuff with image if needed, i.e. cropping:
//ParameterBlock pb = new ParameterBlock();
//pb.addSource(myImageOp);
//pb.add((float)x);
//pb.add((float)y);
//pb.add((float)width);
//pb.add((float)height);
//myImageOp = JAI.create("crop", pb, null);

//save image
String dstImgFile="myImage.tiff";
String dstFileType="TIFF";
JAI.create("filestore", myImageOp, dstImgFile, dstFileType);
```

(also you can put your awt image directly as myImageOp in "filestore" operation)